# Joomla 1.7 ACL issue

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

This website has been up and running for many years without an issue and all of a sudden this message is popping up when we try to access a protected page/document:

```
You requested a page that requires you to login. Please log in and try again
```

But this doesn't make sense because the user is already logged in and they have the correct permission to view the page.  The only component installed on the website is DocMan and the content of the website and the documents are only view-able by Registered users and a couple of other Joomla custom User Groups.

Does anyone know what's the best way to start troubleshooting this issue?  Is there an ACL plugin/component for Joomla 1.7 for troubleshooting?

I can log in to the back-end and browse without any problem. I can also log in to the front-end but when I try to click on any page or document, the above error pops up.

At this point I'm not even 100% sure this is a ACL issue, like I said the error started pupping up since this morning and the previous settings has been working for many years.  Have anyone ever came across an issue similar to this?

Comment: Did you clear all cache  of your browser or tried with another one? You should have a look at your files an database too, maybe you got hacked? J1.7.5 had an end of life till March 2012. And there are many security issues with it. I hope you use this server internally only.

Comment: I have cleared the cache so many times but that didn't help.  How should I check the files in MySQL db, I mean what should I look for to see if the size is hacked or not?

Comment: I found a clue, when I turn off the Search Engine Friendly URLs in global settings, everything starts working again.

Comment: Congrates, but strange behaviour. Nevertheless, keep backups and force updating to J3.5.1

Comment: Sure, but why the website isn't working in Friendly Url mode? It's been working for a long time but all of a sudden Friendly Urls aren't working.  I am checking with the Hosting company to make sure mod_rewrite is still enabled. Anything else might cause this issue that needs attention?

Comment: I remember a security issue (I've one J2.5 site, but most running 3.5) which I updated to the 2.5 manually. Maybe this link is important for you: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/hotfixes/ please search for the 2.5 fix, you should do these steps to secure your site. Did you already update this `libraries/joomla/session/session.php`?

Comment: The site I am working with is on 1.7.0 .. is it still considered as 1.5?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112537/discussion-between-tom-k-and-marz).